# How to customize enlarging a window on a mac pro?

Tags: macos

I'm using a mac book pro.
When I'm pressing the upper left corner green button - it makes the window
into full screen and hides the dock bar.
I want my window to be almost full screen - I want the dock bar to remain.
One option is to manually starch it, but this is something that needs to be done every time.

Is there a way of customizing the upper left green button for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you're looking for is known as "zooming" the window. It used to be that the green button did that, but these days it enters full-screen mode instead. If you hold down the Option key when you click the green button, it reverts to the old zoom operation. You can also use the Zoom item of the Window menu. You can also configure things so that double-clicking on the title bar zooms the window, on the Dock pane of System Preferences.